# Removing emacsen-common Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, uninstall, 16.10, emacs

I've installed emacs via apt-get but then I uninstalled it but this package still remained installed.

When I try to uninstall it it says:

```
sudo apt-get remove emacsen-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (>= 2.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I fix this and uninstall all traces of emacs?

Now I even have this error:

```
sudo apt-get remove emacsen-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 update-manager : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-notifier
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Try purging with `sudo apt-get remove --purge emacsen-common`

Comment: Gives me the same error

Comment: try `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Sadly doesn't work

Comment: You have other package management issues that you need to resolve before Apt lets you install or remove packages. What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?